# mod_wsgi: Global statements execute only when the file is modified

Tags: python, windows, apache, global-variables, mod-wsgi

I'm using python over `mod_wsgi` and I have some statements (debug messages and other things) in the global part of the script (outside the `application` function).
Those global statements are executed only once just after the .py file is modified (touched). If I update the webpage again those statement are not executed until the next time I edit/touch the .py file.

I guess the reason is a caching mechanism at some level (python level? wsgi level?).

Is there something I can configure or anything so that the statement in the global part of the script are always executed?

Answer (score 0):

Read the mod_wsgi documentation on source code reloading.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

In short, use daemon mode not embedded mode and touch the WSGI script file after any changes to any code and it will force a reloaded of the daemon process.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Windows, so I can't use daemon mode

Comment: That document if you read it right to the end, provides a recipe on how you can add a monitor thread in Windows to auto restart only when files changed.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:

```
MaxRequestsPerChild 1
```

Setting apache to process only one request per child before killing it, forces to reload the source code every time.
I don't know if this is the best way, but at least works for now.

Comment: Setting MaxRequestsPerChild to 1 is ill advised.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, yes, for a production server. But I'm in developing stage now.